# Order: An Analysis on Point Sorting

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

So I've made for myself a point printing class, that is supposed to have the user enter in 2-tuples; that is, x and y, that then prints them back to the user in ^order,^ where order means p1=(x,y)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Point2D {
public:
    Point2D();
    Point2D(double a, double b);

    double getx();
    double gety();

    void setx(double a);
    void sety(double b);

    virtual void print();
    virtual void print(int a);

    double angle();

private:
    double x;
    double y;
};

bool operator<( Point2D a , Point2D b );

int main() {

    double my_x=-999;
    double my_y=-999;
    string my_color;
    double my_weight;
    vector<Point2D*> points;

    cout << "Welcome to Point Printer! Please insert the x-and y-coordinates for your points and I will print them in sorted order! Just one rule, the point (0,0) is reserved as the terminating point, so when you are done enter (0,0).\n";

    while(true)
    {
        cout << "x = ";
        cin>>my_x;
        cout << "y = ";
        cin>>my_y;
        if((my_x == 0)&&(my_y==0))
        {
            break;
        }
        points.push_back(new Point2D(my_x, my_y));
    }
    sort(points.begin(), points.end());

    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << "Your points are\n\n";

    for(int i=0;i<points.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<i+1<<": ";
        (*points[i]).print(); cout<<endl; // this is the printing gadget
    }
    for(int i=0; i<points.size(); i++) 
    {
        delete points[i];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    return 0;

}

double Point2D::angle()
{
    double Angle = atan2(y,x);
    if(Angle < 0)
    {
        return Angle + 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679;
    }
    return Angle;
}

bool operator< (Point2D a, Point2D b)
{
    if (a.getx()*a.getx()+a.gety()*a.gety() < b.getx()*b.getx()+b.gety()*b.gety())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (a.getx()*a.getx()+a.gety()*a.gety() > b.getx()*b.getx()+b.gety()*b.gety())
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (a.getx()*a.getx()+a.gety()*a.gety() ==b.getx()*b.getx()+b.gety()*b.gety())
    {
        if (a.angle() < b.angle())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (a.angle() > b.angle())
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

Point2D::Point2D() { x = 0; y = 0; return;}

Point2D::Point2D(double a, double b) { x = a; y = b; return;}

double Point2D::getx() { return x;}
double Point2D::gety() { return y;}

void Point2D::setx(double a) { x = a; return; }
void Point2D::sety(double b) { y = b; return; }

void Point2D::print() {
    cout<<"("<<x<<","<<y<<")";
    return;
}

void Point2D::print(int a) {
    print(); cout<<endl;
}
```

What I'm having trouble with is either one of the following:

> sort
>
> angle()
>
> operator<(Point2D a, Point2D b)
>
> Something different entirely...

In particular, the following points:

```
x = 1
y = 2
x = 2
y = 3
x = 1.1
y = 2.2
x = -10
y = 10
x = -5
y = -3
x = -5
y = 3
x = 5
y = -3
x = 5
y = 3
x = 0
y = 0
```

are not sorted in the correct order.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you have any questions about my code, please ask.

Comment: What "trouble" are you having?

Comment: Your comparison function is extremely redundant.  You make the same two calculations 3 times each.  That's what variables are for.

Comment: The "trouble" that I'm having is that the points that I was supposed to include in the post--adding those now--are not being sorted "correctly" in accordance with the above mentioned scheme.

Comment: Try the program out on your machine, and enter the data points mentioned in the post. I should be getting `1: (1,2)
2: (1.1,2.2)
3: (2,3)
4: (5,3)
5: (-5,3)
6: (-5,-3)
7: (5,-3)
8: (-10,10)`

Comment: Didn't I state how it's redundant in my comment? *"You make the same two calculations 3 times each."* -- Yes, I believe I did state it.

Comment: Your comparison function is broken: it thinks that `x < x`.

Comment: Also, your vector is filled with `Point2D*`, so you are sorting the pointers instead of what they point at.

Comment: Ahh...`vector<Point2D*> points;`  and  `bool operator< (Point2D a, Point2D b)` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (or one of them) is the final statement in your comparison function.

```
return true;
```

Look at this block:

```
if (a.getx()*a.getx()+a.gety()*a.gety() ==b.getx()*b.getx()+b.gety()*b.gety())
{
    if (a.angle() < b.angle())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (a.angle() > b.angle())
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

First of all, if we've gotten to this point, we've determined that the `(x*x + y*y)` calculations for both `a` and `b` are equal.  Now let's assume that the angle is also equal.  What happens?  The first test fails because `a.angle()` is not less than `b.angle()`. Then the second test fails because `a.angle()` is not greater than `b.angle()`.  Then you return true.  In other words, you're saying that it is true that `a` is less than `b`, even though by all rights, they should be considered equal, and so you should return false.  Instead of multiple tests on the angle, you can just `return a.angle() < b.angle();`, and that should do the trick.  With some additional simplifications, your function should look something like this:

```
bool operator<(Point2d a, Point2d b)
{
    double A = a.getx()*a.getx()+a.gety()*a.gety();
    double B = b.getx()*b.getx()+b.gety()*b.gety();

    if (A < B) return true;
    if (A > B) return false;
    return a.angle() < b.angle();
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... Good catch. Thank you, Benjamin Lindley.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you are storing and sorting pointers, not objects. The points will be compared not with your operator but their addresses. Try change points to `vector<Point2d>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all just use  (if your are just planning to sort 2D points) :

(**Edit :** See Benjamin Lindley comments below.)

```
bool operator < ( Point2D a,  Point2D b)
{
    return a.getx() < b.getx() || 
          (a.getx()==b.getx() && a.gety()< b.gety() );
}
```

Another thing if use use `std::cout` in  `operator < ( Point2D a,  Point2D b)`, you will notice it won't be called anytime.

The reason is this:

`vector<Point2D*> points;  // Vector of Point2D*`

but `bool operator< (Point2D a, Point2D b)` is used for comparision.

Suggested Fixes:

```
vector<Point2D> points;

points.push_back(Point2D(my_x, my_y));
```

And accordingly, wherever applicable.

Also you can't define anything like

`bool operator<(const Point2D* a, const Point2D* b)`

Because of this:

> **C++03 standard, §13.5 [over.oper] p6:**
>
> An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or
>   be a non-member function and have at least one parameter whose type is
>   a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an
>   enumeration.

Comment: That operator would result in a completely different order than what he intends.  He appears to be trying to sort the points by distance from origin.